# Are PlayPlugin instances shared between different threads (Play 1.2.5)

Tags: plugins, playframework, thread-safety, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to find out how PlayPlugin objects are used within Play Framework (1.2.5).

Are same PlayPlugin instances shared between different Play threads?

With some source lookup I suppose yes but since Play has some meta-programming in many places and I'm not so familiar with all this, I'm not 100% sure.

Call stack for PlayPlugin.beforeInvocation:

- PlayPlugin.beforeInvocation
- PluginCollection.beforeInvocation

  - list of enabled plugins is a field within PluginCollection)
- Invocation.before

  - uses static field Play.PluginCollection
  - `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(Play.classloader)` is one thing that could possibly affect Play.PluginCollection, for example.

Single instance for all threads -behaviour would also be confirmed by the article [Play Framework: Introduction to Writing Modules](http://www.packtpub.com/article/play-framework-introduction-writing-modules):

> beforeActionInvocation(): This code is executed before controller
>   invocation. Useful for validation, where it is used by Play as well.
>   You could also possibly put additional objects into the render
>   arguments here. Several plugins also set up some variables inside
>   thread locals to make sure they are thread safe.

So, I suppose the answer is that yes, the instances are shared, but would like to confirm that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Each instance of PlayPlugin(subclass of course) is shared throughout the entire JVM. You get that instance via `Play.plugin(class<T> clazz)` method call.